# Oracle all data from :new

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert-update

I want to log a table in another table with before trigger.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    log_row mytable%rowtype;
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
        log_row := :new; --Get all from :new.
        log_row.foo = 1; --I would like to modify one or more values!
        INSERT INTO mytable_log VALUES log_row;
    END IF;
END;
```

It doesn't work. Can I pass all data to log_row from :new somehow?

Thx!

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? Is it logging the wrong (= original) value?

Comment: Mytable has 143 fields and I don't want list all fields.

Comment: Worst case do a small plsql block queriying all_tab_cols, it'll at least generate the required code.